# Replace dash with zero without affecting negative numbers

Tags: r

Is there a way to replace dashes by `NA` or zero without affecting negative values in a vector that resembles the following: `c("-","-121512","123","-")`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do

```
x <- c("-","-121512","123","-")
x[x == "-"] <- NA
x
#[1] NA        "-121512" "123"     NA
```

If you need a numeric vector instead of character wrap `x` in `as.numeric()`.

---

If you want to replace all `"-"` in a dataframe we can use the same logic

```
df1 <- data.frame(x = c("-","-121512","123","-"),
                  y = c("-","-121512","123","-"),
                  z = c("-","A","B","-"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

df1[df1 == "-"] <- NA
```

If you want numeric columns if appropriate then you `type.convert`

```
df1[] <- lapply(df1, type.convert, as.is = TRUE)
str(df1)
'data.frame':   4 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ x: int  NA -121512 123 NA
 $ y: int  NA -121512 123 NA
 $ z: chr  NA "A" "B" NA
```

Comment: @EnesI. Updated my answer.

Answer (score 2):

We can use `na_if`

```
library(dplyr)
na_if(v1, "-") %>% 
    as.numeric
 #[1]      NA -121512     123      NA
```

---

If it is a `data.frame`

```
library(tidyverse)
df1 %>%
   mutate_all(na_if, "-") %>% 
   type_convert
```

#### data

```
v1 <- c("-","-121512","123","-")
```